# How to log a call and send an Email on click of respective fields in custom lightning component

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I have hyperlinked text for phone number and email address on my component. Is there any standard salesforce behaviour for this, and if yes, how do I use it on click of these fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done as :

```
Email: <a href="{!'mailto:'+record.Owner_Employee__r.Email__c}">        {!record.Owner_Employee__r.Email__c}</a>

Phone:<a href="{!'tel:'+record.Owner_Employee__r.Work_Phone__c}">    {!record.Owner_Employee__r.Work_Phone__c}</a>
```